# Unknown type name 'namespace' after install cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, objective-c++

I have a pod and it runs successfully with the default objc project. It also compiles successfully on swift, but when I try to "import myPod" I get: [image]

My pod headers have c++ constructs in #imports in umbrella-header.h

I can add bridging-header.h and my pod will be visible without specifying "import myPod", but is it possible to do this without bridging-header.h? I don't want to use it

Comment: could you share your pod? thanks.

Comment: @Iskandir c++ lib is private but I can  show pod and podspec